# Console in Light Table is not working

Tags: lighttable

I'm a newbie programmar, Working through problem sets, I encountered a weird problem with console in light table. It is not executing codes. I posted an image,  I'd be grateful if anyone could help me out with this.

Thanks.! please visit https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy7q7.jpg for image.

Answer (score 0):

Console in LightTable is not able to execute any code, at least yet. It just a way where you see the log. Moreover, the design of LT makes you execute it inline (for several language) .. Thus be more comfortable.

Cheers.